# Tensorflow in d ifferent IDEs

Tags: python, intellij-idea, tensorflow

I've seen many posts concerning  a variation of the following.  My environment is Windows 10 using Python from Anaconda. Both the latest versions. I'm trying to get Tensorflow to work in the Python IDE or in Jupyter within Intellij. It is in the site package in Anaconda but not in the site-packages in Intellij and therefore not seen as a module. It is, however, available in Jupyter Notebook launched from Anaconda's Navigator. The crux of the problem is why is Tensorflow available in one IDE but not another? I'm looking for a solution not a failed suggestion.

Comment: `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. Maybe some environments come with the package pre-installed. If not, just install it.

Comment: Also please vote for this feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27519